Adding margin to nicematrix does not add space around cells

In the previous image, the space around V vector is provided by margin option while the space around I vector is provided with \hspace{1em}
Although this is what is expected sometimes, it usually neater to provide a new option for margins in nicematrix. The option does not simply move brackets to the left and right by 1em but rather add \hspace{1em} around its contents, allowing \UnderBrace to expand as expected in this example. The name of this option could be margin-real, margin-real-before, margin-real-after
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        Y_{11} & Y_{12} & Y_{13} & Y_{14}
        \\
        Y_{21} & Y_{22} & Y_{23} & Y_{24}
        \\
        Y_{31} & Y_{32} & Y_{33} & Y_{34}
        \\
        Y_{41} & Y_{42} & Y_{43} & Y_{44}
        \\
        \CodeAfter
        \UnderBrace{1-1}{4-4}{Y_{\mathrm{bus}}}[yshift=3pt]
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin=1em]
        V_{1}
        \\
        V_{2}
        \\
        V_{3}
        \\
        V_{4}
        \\
        \CodeAfter
        \UnderBrace{1-1}{4-1}{V_{\mathrm{buses}}}[yshift=3pt]
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
    =
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        \hspace{1em}
        I_{1}
        \hspace{1em}
        \\
        I_{2}
        \\
        I_{3}
        \\
        I_{4}
        \\
        \CodeAfter
        \UnderBrace{1-1}{4-1}{I_{\mathrm{buses}}}[yshift=3pt]
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}


For your one column matrix you can use, e.g., columns-width=3.5em instead of margin=1em as a workaround.

@cabohah. Good solution, but it is still good to provide the option of adding padding to the left and right of columns contents

If you want a new feature you should ask the author/maintainer not us.

I'm not quite sure I understand correctly, but if you are asking for a new option to be added to/implemented in a package, this site is not the best place to ask for it. Instead contact the maintainer of the package through the channels advertised in the documentation. It is true that maintainers of some packages are active on this site and may even pick up suggestions from questions here, but this should not be used as a reason to post feature requests here that are only answerable/actionable for maintainers.

You should post your request on the GitHub depot of nicematrix: https://github.com/fpantigny/nicematrix/issues

Why not a {bNiceArray} with a preamble: {>{\hspace{1em}}c<{\hspace{1em}}}?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{>{\hspace{1em}}c<{\hspace{1em}}}
  I_{1}
  \\
  I_{2}
  \\
  I_{3}
  \\
  I_{4}
  \\
  \CodeAfter
  \UnderBrace{1-1}{4-1}{I_{\mathrm{buses}}}[yshift=3pt]
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}


